# Array reduce used for sum. How to implement exclusions found in a different array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following object and function to sum the values of the object keys. How can I do the same thing but make sure not to include accounts in a `_ignore` array?

```js
const _balances = {
  "0x000000000": 100,
  "0xCONTRACTOR": 200,
  "0xALICE": 300,
  "0xBOB": 400,
  "0xCHARLIE": 500,
};

function circulatingSupply() {
  // Total number of tokens that are currently in circulation and are held by various accounts.
  return Object.values(_balances).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}

const CS = circulatingSupply();

console.info("Circulating Supply:", CS);
```

So what if I had another array whose account names should not be part of array reduce sum?

```
const _ignore = [
  "0x000000000",
  "0xCONTRACTOR",
];
```

I confess array reduce is a bit overwhelming..

Comment: "*I confess array reduce is a bit overwhelming.*" yes. Yet YOU DON'T HAVE TO DO IT WITH REDUCE! You could, you know, filter out the keys/values *before* calling `.reduce()` on the array. Which is *much* simpler to work with.

Comment: Ha! Naturally I did wrong. Reduce has a way of letting noobs do that.

Comment: It does. But if you don't want to be overwhelmed by it, then why not take the simpler approach?

Comment: Excellent point. Just feels like understanding array reduce makes you a better programmer than those who don't.

Comment: I thought understanding programming makes you better. And knowing *what you're trying to do* falls under that. It's not a particular function you need - you need the process. It's a bit like saying "driving an excavator makes you a better bartender. Because you *can*, if you're persistent, be able to open a beer bottle with the excavator".

Comment: HAHAHA! I see your point. Well, would you say a programmer who's able to understand array reduce had to have explored the language substantially more then one who doesn't? Would it be a deal braker if you were interviewing someone for a job and they couldn't tell you how it works?

Comment: "*Would it be a deal braker if you were interviewing someone for a job and they couldn't tell you how it works?*" not at all. In fact, a candidate might score *extra points* if they can tell me when *not to use it*. But there would probably be no points awarded for just explaining `.reduce()` to me.

Comment: That really makes me feel better about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const _balances = {
  "0x000000000": 100,
  "0xCONTRACTOR": 200,
  "0xALICE": 300,
  "0xBOB": 400,
  "0xCHARLIE": 500,
};

const _ignore = [
  "0x000000000",
  "0xCONTRACTOR",
];

function circulatingSupply() {
  // Total number of tokens that are currently in circulation and are held by various accounts.
  return Object.entries(_balances).reduce((a, [key, value]) => _ignore.includes(key) ? a : a + value, 0);
}

const CS = circulatingSupply();

console.info("Circulating Supply:", CS);
```

Answer (score 1):

First make the function take a list as param:

```
function circulatingSupply(list) {
  // Total number of tokens that are currently in circulation and are held by various accounts.
  return Object.values(list).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}
```

Then create a new list without the other values

```
const newList = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(_balances).filter(([key, value]) => !_ignoredValues.includes(key)))
```

Pass it to the function:

```
console.log(circulatingSupply(newList))
```